# Why the Unity3D only can load 32-bit native plugin(.so) on android platform?

Tags: unity-game-engine, 64-bit, native, android-unity-plugin

I built a native plugin (shared library, .so) for ARM64-v8 on android platform.

It works well with the plain android apps.

But, when the Unity3D loads it, I just got an error message with "... .so is 64-bit instead of 32-bit....".

I just tried to use **il2cpp** to build the 64-bit app with Unity3D, but it also doesn't work.

**Does the Unity3D not support 64-bit native plugin on android platform?**

Or

**How can I use it, 64-bit native plugin on android platform?**

Please let me get some idea.

Thanks.

Currently the tools what I use are as follow:

**OS - Windows 10 64-bit**

**Unity3D (Editor?) - 5.5.03f Personal (64-bit)**

**AndroidNDK64 - android NDK r10e for il2cpp**

Comment: What directory in your Unity Project did you put the .so plugin?

Comment: @Programmer I have just tried it in Assets/Plugins.

Comment: No. There are two known valid [directory](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/PluginsForAndroid.html) for Android plugin.  `Assets/Plugins/Android/libs/x86/` **and** `Assets/Plugins/Android/libs/armeabi-v7a/`. Put it in `Assets/Plugins/Android/libs/x86_64/`. Let me know if that actually work. x86_64 is for 64 bit. Maybe it is not supported but try that first.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unity does not currently support 64-bit native plugins on Android. So you must use a 32-bit version. Notice the values for the "Architecture" option in the Player Settings for the Android target (in the Unity Editor). They are ARMv7 and x86, both 32-bit architectures.

Unity could support 64-bit targets for Android at some point in the future, but I don't know of any current plans to do so.

Comment: This is what I thought. What if you create a [`x86_64`](https://developer.android.com/ndk/guides/x86-64.html#over) folder in the `Assets/Plugins/Android` dir? Will this work?

Comment: Thanks, Josh.
Then, does **il2cpp** only work on **iOS** to build one for 64-bit architecture?

Comment: @Programmer No, that will not make 64-bit plugins work on Android. They are simply not supported.

Comment: @TwisTeDStRiDeR No, on iOS both 32-bit and 64-bit are supported. By default, an iOS build with IL2CPP will create a universal binary with both architecture slices.